# Incremental Load from servicenow to azure sql in ADF

Tags: sharepoint, azure-sql-database, auto-increment

I want to do incremental load from servicenow to Azure SQL DB using ADF. Can someone please suggest me the easy and quick way .

Answer (score 0):

The same question has been answered [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/661230/incremental-load-from-sharepoint-list-to-azure-sql.html). Posting the same here to help other community members in SO.

There is no direct way of implementing an incremental load from a SharePoint list, however, you could use `$filter` query parameter on `Modified` attribute of your SharePoint list. So, if you are using Copy Data activity then you need to configure source like below:

[image: check the image for your reference]

with Query:

```
@concat('$filter=Modified ge datetime''',formatDateTime(variables('WatermarkDate'), 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss'),'''')
```

Here, I am taking the initial watermark date from a variable, but you need to store it somewhere permanently (like in Azure SQL) from where fetch date as your watermark date.

Once you have done with the data load, you could use the lookup activity to get `Modified` column from the latest modified entry of your SharePoint list and update your stored watermark date for the next load starting point.

Please check the below GIF for your reference. You could tweak it accordingly to fit your needs.

[image: check the GIF for your reference]